# keep getting error when trying to append to a list

Tags: python

Hello I have some code here

```
grid2 = [
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0]
    ]

terms = ["hello", "later", "no", "dog","love"]
d1 = ["hello", "no", "later", "cry","puppy","mouse"]
d2 = ["baby", "venus", "poop", "hello","puppy","mouse"]
d3 = ["mole", "no", "mars", "eat","dog","mouse"]


for i, val in enumerate(terms):
    grid2[i] = val
    if val in d1:
        grid2[i].append(1)
    if val in d2:
        grid2[i].append(2)
    if val in d3:
        grid2[i].append(3)
```

what I'm trying to do is add the term from terms into the first array position then a 2d array to the first array if the item from terms is found in d1,d2,d3 my end result should look some like this.

```
[['hello', 'd1', 'd2'], ['later', 'd1']]
```

I eventually want the term with a list of documents(d1) they are in
but i keep getting the error

```
str object has no attribute append on grid2[i].append(1)
```

when I try this line by itself it works and appends the value to grid2[0]

```
grid2[0].append("d1")
```

Thanks

Comment: I am voting to close this as off-topic as it is simply a typographical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i, val in enumerate(terms):
    grid2[i] = val
```

After executing that second line, `grid2[i]` is no longer a list; it's a string.

Perhaps you meant `grid2[i][0] = val`?